# What to do about permanently outdated questions/answers on SU

Tags: discussion, questions

I like Super User, often I have only to write the title of my question on the "Ask Question" page and the answer shows up in the "Related Questions"

Thus I want to keep it great.

Computer hardware questions is always getting outdated and doubly so when price is discussed.

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/105221/alienware-worth-the-money-suggestions-for-a-build-up-gaming-computer-closed) got closed as a dupe, but I agree with one of the comments that a dupe from six moths ago is not relevant from a computer-hardware/price question today.

In my opinion it should probably have been allowed or perhaps closed as To Localized instead.

**But here is my main question**
What should we do about old hardware questions? A search about best/$ *Frobnac* is bound to be irrelevant afer six months (or even earlier)

Comment: Related situation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36296/should-we-close-old-questions-with-no-more-feedback-as-no-longer-relevant-on-s

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Close them as "No longer relevant"

Comment: I agree... except this is one case where it wouldn't be fair to remove any rep accrued by the questioner or answerers (as has been proposed, and IMHO is generally a good idea). They were posting in good faith at the time.

Comment: So close, but don't delete. No trouble there.

Comment: The irony here is that this answer itself is no longer relevant, because that close reason is now gone!

Answer (score 7):

> I like Super User, often I have only to write the title of my question on the "Ask Question" page and the answer shows up in the "Related Questions"
>
> Thus I want to keep it great.

That's great. That's the attitude that makes these sites great.

> Computer hardware questions is always getting outdated and doubly so when price is discussed.

I don't think that price should be discussed on SU, as that is too localized for an international audience these sites have.

> This question got closed as a dupe, but I agree with one of the comments that a dupe from six moths ago is not relevant from a computer-hardware/price question today.

I think that [Is it still cheaper to build your own PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/1661/is-it-still-cheaper-to-build-your-own-pc) is a bit more generic. In the last 15 years [Roalt's](https://superuser.com/questions/1661/is-it-still-cheaper-to-build-your-own-pc/1687#1687) and [TheTXI's](https://superuser.com/questions/1661/is-it-still-cheaper-to-build-your-own-pc/1684#1684) answers it has been true, and it is likely to continue to be true for some time (IMHO). Also, it's a community wiki question, so anybody can jump in and update it anytime.

> In my opinion it should probably have been allowed or perhaps closed as To Localized instead.

I'd have closed as too localized the original, the second one is a tad more generic.

> But here is my main question:
> What should we do about old hardware questions? A search about best/$ *Frobnac* is bound to be irrelevant afer six months (or even earlier)

Then close as no longer relevant in six months, update it if you have the edit powers, or/and ask it again pointing to the outdated question, letting the community decide the appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 6):

I say keep them. They may be outdated to *you* in 6 months, but i promise you someone 2, 3, 4 or more years down the line will have picked up hardware xyz off ebay or still has it running.

Hardware has a surprising ability to stick around for years and years, even after most people have moved on.

Comment: SU can be an excellent source of information re using less current equipment/ equipment which isnot any longer supported, yet which is still in use.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally speaking, all questions should remain live and constantly updated and kept relevant through edits and new submissions. **But that's not reality.**

Many technology questions have a limited lifetime. It is simply unlikely that new answers will be add and voted up while older, out-dated answers will be voted down and pushed out of relevance.

*[As a side note, this is the very reason we should not encourage localized "what's the best price/technology/etc" questions unless they are posed in the context of an EXTREMELY specific situation.]*

It's a tough question and one that **will plague Super User sooner than Stack Overflow or Server Fault**. I think the best near-term solution is to at least attempt to close older questions as:

> **[closed -- no longer relevant]**

They will remain in the system for archival value and users who answered the questions will not lose the reputation.

Long term...? That's another discussion.

Comment: "Many technology questions have a limited lifetime.": true, but that limit is far longer than many of us would like. (E.g. 6 year old computers are going to be quite common in homes, many never updated since.)

Comment: E.g. see this SF question: http://serverfault.com/questions/110157/windows-98-clients-locking-up-during-files-ops-with-server-2003

Comment: But "many technology questions" go beyond trouble shooting hardware/software. Consider all the "best of" questions: best price, best technology, best practices, fastest, most reliable... They are often *very* localized to the time frame they are being asked. Legacy support or not, surely you can see that *"Best Laptop for Student?"* -type questions will become irrelevant (and *blatantly* incorrect) in short order. I don't foresee them being kept up to date. Better to be [closed -- no longer relevant]. **Those are the questions I am talking about.**

Comment: If question is localized to the time frame, that time frame should be specifien. No longer relevant is too broad - when it was relevant? In 2012? 2011? 
A periodized #archive# flag could be the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Another random opinion, since this doesn't just apply to old hardware, but can apply to software too:  rather than close, how about an [archive] tag - a special tag that wouldn't show up in any searches unless it was explicitly included.