# What to do about outdated questions now that "no longer relevant" doesn't exist as a close reason?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

There used to be a [close reason called "no longer relevant" that we were supposed to use](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/798/what-to-do-about-permanently-outdated-questions-answers-on-su), but it [no longer exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38710/what-happened-to-close-reason-no-longer-relevant).

What should we do instead in this day and age?

Comment: BTW, one of the linked questions focuses on hardware shopping questions, for which we have a different close reason now.  My question was prompted by a software question, though.

Comment: I think using custom close reason is an alternative? Though usually I believe there's a reason why the question is no longer relevant, which I guess is an acceptable answer.

Comment: What would be your criteria for "no longer relevant" if we still had such a close reason?

Comment: The question involved workarounds for limitations in old versons of Chrome OS.  It's confusing to users of modern versions but could be possibly relevant to someone with an old, unsupported device.  But Chrome OS isn't versoned like say Mac or Windows, so you can't tag it like you could [windows-95].

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use one of the close reasons we **do** have.

That close reason was removed 8 years ago according to the date of that meta question and it mentions using "too localised" instead.

I would say that our current reasons of "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking" can, depending on the situation, fit the same purpose as "no longer relevant".

The meta question you linked has an example of why "no longer relevant" was required:

> The problem "solved itself", no accepted answer, nothing. It's a typical case of a "situation" which is no longer relevant.

For me "too broad" also fits, as there is no way to know what fixed it. If a problem fixes itself without any rhyme or reason then by definition the question does not contain enough detail with which to explain what fixed it.

Comment: Any question on the site could become outdated at any minute, that's the nature of computing.  "Too localized" isn't a proper close response for this, or I could close half the questions on the site on that basis.

Comment: Also I don't necessarily want to close it, I only mentioned it because apparently that was what we were supposed to do 8 years ago. If the answer is just leave it open and let users be confused if they don't happen to see my comment then so be it.